# sorting a vector of a member inside the struct C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Hi I would like to sort the members of a vector. I've seen similar problems but the errors faced is different. I follow the "sort" steps at cplusplus.com

```
struct Food {
   char[8] Name;
   float Price; 
}
```

And I have a vector

```
std::vector<Food> FoodList;
```

And I have a compare function:

```
bool comparePrice (Food f1, Food f2) { return (f1.Price<f2.Price); }
```

And final my sort statement:

```
std::sort(FoodList.begin(),FoodList.end(),comparePrice);
```

But I am experiencing an error that the sort expects 2 arguments but I gave 3. But when I was writing the program in MVS2010, it prompts me to enter 3 arguments. Can somebody help?

Comment: When posting question about errors, please provide the exact and complete error. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: And I'm surprised that you get errors about that (valid) `std::sort` call, but not the structure definition which its illegal field definition?

Comment: char[8] Name should rather be char Name[8]..

Comment: Is your `comparePrice()` a member function? If so, it must be static.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code, see comments below:

```
struct Food {
   char[8] Name; // this should be: char Name[8];, and even better std::string
   float Price; 
} // missing semicolon here ;

// You should use const Food& as parameter type
bool comparePrice (Food f1, Food f2) { return (f1.Price<f2.Price); }
```

Comment: But according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort you don't have to use constant references as function arguments.

Comment: You have: `The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
 bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b); `. On my VS2005 compiler, this compiles even with `(Food f1, Food f2)`. Using `const T&` is actually good practice, you dont copy by value (thats efficient), and const says that your function is not changing arguments.